MDriven Modelr reset zoom?
Maybe I'm just blind, but is there any way in MDriven Framework Modelr (modeler) to reset zoom level to 100 % (or whatever the default zoom level is)?
Preferably for all diagrams at once...

Nha - don't think so.
But workaround: Right-click-menu, Extras, Open model debugger,
Action:
Diagram.allinstances->collect(d|d.ZoomScaleFactor:=1.0)

